# vaadin grid table column width control with css

Tags: html, css, polymer-2.x

In my **Polymer 2.0** project I have using **vaadin-grid#3.0.2**. There is a grid with some large number of data - 20+ columns, so that have an overflow-y scrolling within the div. Because of the large number, columns width decreases inside the grid. Parent div have a `display: flex` property, so that the width of columns are auto-generated. **Can we set minimum width for columns with CSS? or Can I control it with CSS?**

*Can't reproduce the problem code here because tha data comes from an external server (Oracle VM VirtualBox).*

Here is the code that used in HTML:

```
<vaadin-grid class="projectworksheet" name="worksheet" items="[[projectData]]" page-size="10"></vaadin-grid>
```

Here is a screenshot of the rendered grid, vaadin-grid automatically generated `<vaadin-grid-table id="scroller">` under `#shadow-root` I think, that's why I can't control columns `min-width` with CSS.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS alone you can't cross shadow dom boundaries, meaning you won't be able to set the width from outside the vaadin-grid component unless they have provided a mixin or a css variable.

However you can use javascript to access elements inside the shadowDom and set their css properties. eg: `document.querySelector('vaadin-grid.projectworksheet').shadowRoot.querySelector('vaadin-grid div.col').style.width = '100px'`

Comment: Is it need any function? or just with doc `querySelector`?

Comment: You can try it in the console, just that line should work if it can find the correct element. Try is part by part.

Comment: You can debug with document.querySelectorAll('*') Also you need to use querySelector for every time you have to access elements inside shadowDom